# Memory Segmentation Simulation

Tags: java, object-oriented, memory-management, simulation

I recently have been working on a project to simulate segmentation in memory. I wanted to create everything from scratch; not use pre-built data structures.

I create a memory object that allows for "segment" nodes and "hole" nodes.

**A segment is:** Any location in the memory object that is occupied by data.

**A hole is:** Any location in memory that is currently vacant and can be occupied by data.

---

**Constraints:**

- There can never be 2 adjacent holes in memory
- The head node must always point to the lowest address in memory.

---

**Problems encountered:**

- Correctly setting location for each node; sometimes nodes share a location, incorrectly.
- printLayout() is supposed to print memory nodes in order of ascending location, but does not.

**Seeking:**

- Analysis of implementation
- Possible efficiency improvements
- Any bugs encountered (with corrections, if possible)
- Possible memory leaks

---

**Test files:**

*For testing "R" command*

```
 N
 R 1000 5 100 80 10000
 P
 E
```

*For testing "A" command*

```
N
C 100
A 20 10
A 50 5
A 70 20
P
E
```

---

**Code:**

```
    /********************************************************************************
 *  @author       Evan Bechtol (ecb120030)
 *                <h1>Project: Memory Segmentation Simulation</h1>
 *                <p>Simulation of arrivals/departures/placements of segments in a 
 *                segmented virtual memory, through the use of a linked-list. Implements a 
 *                next-fit policy. Constraints: There can never be neighboring holes.</p>
 *  @since        2015-2-13
 *  @see         http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-to-bubble-sort
 *  @see         http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf
 *  @see         http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list/Removal
 *  @see         http://crunchify.com/a-simple-singly-linked-list-implementation-in-java/
 *  
 ********************************************************************************/

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Creates nodes to be used as data containers in the Memory class
 */
class Node {
    boolean segment;        // Equals false if this Node represents a hole
    int     location;       // Position in memory of first byte
    int     size;           // Size that node occupies
    int     timeToDepart;   // Only valid when this Node represents a segment
    Node    next;

    /** 
     * Constructor for generating a segment in memory
     * 
     * @param   locn        location of node to be created 
     * @param   sz          size of node to be created
     * @param   endOfLife   the timeOfDay node is to depart
     * @param   nxt         specifies the next node to reference in the list
     */
    Node (int locn, int sz, int endOfLife, Node nxt) {
        segment      = true;
        location     = locn;
        size         = sz;
        timeToDepart = endOfLife;
        next         = nxt;
    }

    /** 
     * Constructor for a hole   
     * 
     * @param   locn    location of hole to be created
     * @param   sz      size of hole to be created
     * @param   nxt     reference to next node in the list
     */
    Node (int locn, int sz, Node nxt) {
        segment     = false;
        location    = locn;
        size        = sz;
        next        = nxt;
    }
} // End Node class

/**
 *  Creates a linked-list of ndoes to simulate virtual memory segments and holes
 */
class Memory {
    private static int memorySize;  // Defines the total size for the memory
    Node head;                      // Refers to first node in memory
    Node lastPlacement;             // Refers to the last node that was placed, or hole if the last placed segment is removed

    /**
     * Constructor for Memory, generates a single hole Node of the given size   
     * 
     * @param   size    initial size of memory object
     */
    Memory (int size) {
            memorySize = size;
            Node n = new Node (0, memorySize, null);
            lastPlacement = head = n;
    }

    /** 
     *  Attempts to place a request using the Next Fit Policy. Returns false if there
     *  isn't a hole big enough. Prints a confirmation if placed; return true   
     *  
     *  @param      size        size of placement to be made
     *  @param      timeOfDay   the time at which the placement is being made
     *  @param      lifeTime    how long the segment is to remain in memory
     *  @param      verbose     specifies if extra placement information is to be given
     *  @return     boolean: returns true if the placement was successful
     */
    boolean place (int size, int timeOfDay, int lifeTime, boolean verbose) {

        // If the list is empty, we can place as head node
        if (isEmpty()) {
            Node current = new Node (0, size, 0, null);
            lastPlacement = head = current;
            return true;
        }
        // There are nodes in the list
        else {
            Node current = lastPlacement; //We start searching for a hole at our lastPlacement

            //While there are still nodes to reverse, keep looking
            while (current != null) {
                // If we are looking at a hole
                if (!current.segment && current.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay) {
                    // If the hole is larger or equal to the size we need
                    if (current.size >= size) {
                        Node n = new Node (current.location, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current.next); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart
                        current.next = n;
                        current.size = current.size - size; // Adjust size of hole after placing segment
                        lastPlacement = current = n;

                        // If verbose == true, print the confirmation
                        if (verbose) {
                            System.out.println ("Segment at location: " + lastPlacement.location + "\twith size: " + lastPlacement.size + "\tdeparts at: " + lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                current = current.next;
            } // End while

            current = this.head; // To traverse from start of list

            //While there are still nodes to reverse, keep looking
            while (current != lastPlacement) {
                // If we are looking at a hole
                if (!current.segment && current.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay) {
                    // If the hole is larger or equal to the size we need
                    if (current.size >= size) {
                        Node n = new Node (current.location + size, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current.next); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart
                        current.next = n;
                        current.size = current.size - size;
                        lastPlacement = current =  n;

                        // If verbose == true, print the confirmation
                        if (verbose) {
                            System.out.println ("Segment at location: " + lastPlacement.location + "\twith size: " + lastPlacement.size + "\tdeparts at: " + lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                current = current.next;
            } // End while
        }
        // If we reach this point, segment could not be placed
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *  Remove segments from the list, which are ready to depart.
     *  <p>Checks the following conditions:<ul><li>
     *      1) Head is segment and ready to depart
     *      2) Current is segment and ready to depart
     *      3) Previous is hole, current is hole
     *      4) We are combining the node containing last placement, with another node</li></ul></p>
     *  
     *  @param  timeOfDay   time at which the removal is being done
     */
    void removeSegmentsDueToDepart (int timeOfDay) {

        // Case 1: Head is segment and ready to depart
        if ((head.segment == true) && (head.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay)) {
            head.segment = false; // Allow node to become a hole
            //System.out.println ("Case 1.");
        }

        // Create reference to head node
        Node previous = head;
        // Begin iterating on list from 2nd node
        while (previous.next != null) {
            //Use this as our current position
            Node current = previous.next;  

            // Case 2: Current is segment and ready to depart
            if ((current.segment == true) && (current.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay)) {

                //Combine
                current.segment = false;
                //System.out.println ("Case 2.");

            }

            // Case 3: previous is hole, current is hole
            if ((previous.segment == false) && (current.segment == false)) {
                // Case 4: We are combining the node containing last placement, with another node
                if (current == lastPlacement) {
                    // Set last placement to the node to be combined to
                    lastPlacement = previous;
                    //System.out.println ("Case 4.");
                }
                // Combine
                previous.size += current.size;
                previous.next = current.next;
            }
            // Else we adjust our position.
            else {
                previous = current;
            }
        } // End while
    }

    /** 
     * Print a 3-column tab-separated list of all segments in Memory.
     * Displayed in ascending order of location.    
     */
    void printLayout() {
        Node current = head;
        int numNodes = 0; // Number of nodes in the array
        while (current != null) {
            numNodes++;
            current = current.next;
        }
        //System.out.println (counter);
        Node [] nodeArray = new Node [numNodes];
        int y = 0; // Used as increment in while-loop

        current = head;
        // Loop to print out all segments present
        while (current != null) {
            // Assign nodeArray a node for each index
            nodeArray[y] = current;
            y++;
            current = current.next;
        }// End while

        // Sort the array
        nodeArray = sort (nodeArray, numNodes);

        // Print the sorted array of nodes
        for (int i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
            System.out.println (nodeArray[i].location + "\t" + nodeArray[i].size + "\t" + nodeArray[i].timeToDepart);
        }
    }

    /** 
     * Use a bubble sort to sort the node array by location in ascending order
     * 
     * @param   node    Node array that contains the nodes to be sorted in ascending order
     * @param   length  How many nodes there are  to be sorted
     * @return  Node[]  Returns sorted Node array.
     */
    Node [] sort (Node [] node, int length)
    {
        Node tempNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < ( length - 1 ); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {

              // Sort the array by location in ascending order
              if (node[j].location > node[j + 1].location) 
              {
                tempNode    = node[j];
                node[j]     = node[j + 1];
                node[j + 1] = tempNode;
              }
            }
          }
        return node;
    }

    /** 
     * Determines the empty or occupied state of the list
     * 
     * @return  Returns true if list is empty
     * @return  Returns false if nodes are in the list
     */ 
    public boolean isEmpty () {
        if (head == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
} // End Memory class


/**
 * Class to test Memory and Node classes. Accepts file-redirection from commandline by using the 
 * scanner with System.in, can also accept file input by using scanner with new File        
 */
public class EVBEP1 {

    /**
     * Used to test implementation of Memory and Node objects. Processes commands received through
     * either the commandline or file-input.
     * 
     * @param   args                   Standard parameter for parsing commands received
     * @throws  FileNotFoundException  If file is unable to be located, exception is thrown 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // Used for accepting command line arguments
        //Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        // Used for testing purposes
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("p115sd5.txt")); //Place file name here for different tests
        String line = "";
        boolean done = false;
        Memory memory = new Memory(0); // Memory object
        int  timeOfDay = 0;      // Simulated wall clock, begins with value zero
        int  placements = 0;     // Number of placements completed, begins with value zero
        long totalSpaceTime = 0; // Sum of placed segmentSize(i) x segmentLifetime(i)       
        float meanOccupancy = 0;

        // Loop runs as long as done != true
        while (!done) {
            line = sc.nextLine();   // Store data gathered from file into String
            String [] tokens = line.split(" "); // Split the string using space as delimiter

            // Switch for processing commands received
            switch (tokens[0]) {

            // Print name followed by newline
            case "N": {
                    System.out.println("Evan Clay Bechtol");
                    break;
                }

            // Create a memory object of size s
            case "C": {
                    memory = new Memory(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1])); // Create a new Memory object
                    break;
                }

            // End of data file, print newline and exit
            case "E": {
                    System.out.println();
                    done = true;    // Break the loop, end the program
                    break;
                }

            // Add segment of size 'u' and lifetime 'v' and print confirmation record
            case "A": {
                    int size = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                    int lifeTime = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    timeOfDay++;

                    memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);

                    // Boolean controls whether confirmation is printed.
                    while (!memory.place(size, timeOfDay, lifeTime, true)) {
                        timeOfDay++;
                        memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                        } // End while
                    placements++;

                    // Print confirmation message
                    System.out.printf("Segment of size\t%4d", size);
                    System.out.printf(" placed at time\t%4d", timeOfDay);
                    System.out.printf(" at location\t%4d", memory.lastPlacement.location);
                    System.out.printf(" departs at\t%4d", memory.lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                    break;  
                }

            // Print the current segments in the list
            case "P": {
                    System.out.println ();
                    memory.printLayout();
                    //System.out.println ("End at time: " + timeOfDay);
                    break;
                }

            case "R": {
                    int size = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]); // Size
                    memory = new Memory(size);
                    int minSegSize = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);   // Minimum seg. size
                    int maxSegSize = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);   // Maximum seg. size
                    int maxLifeTime = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);  // Maximum lifetime of segs.
                    int numSegs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);      // Number of segs. to simulate
                    timeOfDay = 0;
                    placements = 0;
                    Random ran = new Random (); // "Random" number generator

                    while (placements < numSegs) {
                        timeOfDay++;
                        memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                        int newSegSize = minSegSize + ran.nextInt(maxSegSize - minSegSize + 1);
                        int newSegLifetime = 1 + ran.nextInt(maxLifeTime);
                        totalSpaceTime += newSegSize * newSegLifetime;

                        while (!memory.place(newSegSize, timeOfDay, newSegLifetime, false)) {
                            timeOfDay++;
                            memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                        } // End while
                        placements++;
                    } // End while

                    // Print final summary of execution
                    meanOccupancy = totalSpaceTime / (timeOfDay);
                    System.out.printf ("Number of placements made =  %6d\n", placements);
                    System.out.printf ("Mean occupancy of memory  = %8.2f\n", meanOccupancy);
                }
            } // End switch
        } // End while
        sc.close();
    } // End main
} // End EVBEP1 class
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This looks like a pretty complex project I'm sure our Java experts will appreciate, I hope you get some good reviews!

Comment: @Phrancis Thank you for the welcome! I certainly hope that I can get some valuable feedback, I want to get this project to 100% and am definitely in need of some fresh eyes to look at it.

Comment: @phrancis would you mind bumping this to a friend/someone who would know about Java in general?

Comment: I pinged a few people to have a look. Just be patient, code reviews take a lot longer to write than your average Stack Overflow answer :)

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: @barq I'm using 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What I Liked

I liked that you had good comments, especially at the beginning of each function.  I was able to read through your code very easily.  There were a few comments that were distracting (e.g. `// End while`), but I would always prefer to err on the side of more comments rather than less.

In your question, I liked how you explained the difference between a segment and a hole, and how you explained the constraints.  I think you should copy this information into your code as comments.

### Bugs

I ran your program and spotted the following bug.  If you use this input file:

```
C 1000
A 100 10
A 50 10
A 50 10
P
E
```

You get this output:

```
0       800     0
0       100     11
50      50      13
50      50      12
```

As you can see, all 3 segments created overlap, and they also overlap with the hole.

The culprit is this code here:

```
                if (current.size >= size) {
                    Node n = new Node (current.location, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current.next); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart
                    current.next = n;
                    current.size = current.size - size; // Adjust size of hole after placing segment
                    lastPlacement = current = n;

                    // If verbose == true, print the confirmation
                    if (verbose) {
                        System.out.println ("Segment at location: " + lastPlacement.location + "\twith size: " + lastPlacement.size + "\tdeparts at: " + lastPlacement.timeToDepart);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
```

Here, you allocate the memory segment from the start of the hole, `current.location`.  But you don't adjust the hole correctly.  For example, with if you have a hole at `0..999` and you place a size 100 block, you should end up with a segment at `0..99` and a hole at `100..999`.  But instead, you end up with a hole at `0..899`.  What you are missing is this line:

```
            current.location += size;
```

Of course, once you do this, you need to adjust your code because the segment you create needs to now come **before** the old segment in the list.  Or you could do it the other way and allocate from the end of the hole.

### Duplicated Code

Regarding that piece of code from above, I noticed two other things:

1) You have two nearly identical copies of the same code for placing the segment.  You should write a common function and call that function from the two places.

2) Those pieces of code are *nearly* identical, but they aren't.  The difference is:

```
Node n = new Node (current.location, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current.next); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart
// Versus:
Node n = new Node (current.location + size, size, timeOfDay + lifeTime, current.next); //timeOfDay + lifeTime = timeToDepart
```

I suspect that you added the `+ size` to the second one because it made some test case with 2 segments work correctly.  But in actuality, that second version is wrong once you fix the earlier bug I mentioned.

### Confusing Code

In the comments for your `Node` structure, it says this:

```
int     timeToDepart;   // Only valid when this Node represents a segment
```

But in the placement code, it does this:

```
if (!current.segment && current.timeToDepart <= timeOfDay) {
```

According to the comment, `timeToDepart` doesn't have a meaning for a hole.  So the if statement shouldn't be checking `timeToDepart` since it is looking for a hole.

Another thing that confused me was this comment:

```
        //While there are still nodes to reverse, keep looking
```

I don't understand what you meant by "reverse".

### Cleaning Up

I noticed that if you completely fill a hole with a segment, you end up with a zero length hole.  That doesn't seem too useful, and if you print out the memory table, it looks a little confusing to have a zero length hole in the list.  I suggest checking for that case and not leaving zero length holes lying around.

Also, it seems to me that the node list is always maintained in a sorted order.  Therefore, I don't see the need to have a `sort()` function.

### Fixed Version

Here is how I changed your code to fix everything mentioned above.  You may choose to do things differently, since the way I added the new node may not be as intuitive as you would like.  I actually create a new hole node and convert the existing hole into a segment.

Also notice that in a few places I use an early `return` from the function to reduce the indentation level of the rest of the code.  That makes things slightly easier to read.

```
boolean tryplace(Node current, int size, int timeOfDay, int lifeTime,
        boolean verbose) {

    // If we are not looking at a hole, or the hole is too small, abort.
    if (current.segment || current.size < size)
        return false;

    int remainingSpace = current.size - size;

    // Convert the current hole into a segment.
    current.size         = size;
    current.segment      = true;
    current.timeToDepart = timeOfDay + lifeTime;

    // If there is any remaining space, create a new node representing
    // the leftover hole.
    if (remainingSpace > 0) {
        // Create a new hole with the remaining space.
        Node remainingHole = new Node (current.location+size,
                                remainingSpace, current.next);
        current.next  = remainingHole;
        lastPlacement = remainingHole;
    } else {
        lastPlacement = current;
    }

    // If verbose == true, print the confirmation
    if (verbose) {
        System.out.println ("Segment at location: " + current.location +
                "\twith size: " + current.size +
                "\tdeparts at: " + current.timeToDepart);
    }

    return true;
}
// ...
boolean place (int size, int timeOfDay, int lifeTime, boolean verbose) {

    // If the list is empty, we can place as head node
    if (isEmpty()) {
        Node current = new Node (0, size, 0, null);
        lastPlacement = head = current;
        return true;
    }

    // We start searching for a hole at our lastPlacement
    Node current = lastPlacement;

    while (current != null) {
        if (tryplace(current, size, timeOfDay, lifeTime, verbose))
            return true;
        current = current.next;
    }

    current = this.head; // Wraparound to start of list

    while (current != lastPlacement) {
        if (tryplace(current, size, timeOfDay, lifeTime, verbose))
            return true;
        current = current.next;
    }

    // If we reach this point, segment could not be placed
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I truly appreciate your time and effort in my problem, especially after it has been sitting for so long unanswered! I'll take a look at your implementation shortly.